# Printer State: Idle - /usr/lib/cups/backend/dnssd failed

Tags: printing, idle

A printer was installed and worked but does not now. A job is successfully submitted, but keeps waiting there for printing (as seen from `lpq` command).

Ping to printer works fine. (The printer is on and works as it prints from Windows.) But on the Printer Property, it shows Printer State: **Idle -** `/usr/lib/cups/backend/dnssd failed`.

The following command does not help either.

> sudo service avahi-daemon restart

Does any one has a solution? Thank you for help.

Answer (score 5):

The problem disappears after the driver is re-installed.

Comment: Please mark it as solved. :)